# Scala - Functions and Closures (Ch. 8, Odersky et al., 2010)

Tags: scala, function

I am new to Scala. I created a script called "LongLines.scala" in IntelliJ with  code in Listing 8.1 (see image below).

**Problem:** If I put FindLongLines object into the same "LongLines.scala" script, the terminal outputs:

```
$ scala FindLongLines 45 LongLines.scala
No such file or class on classpath: FindLongLines
```

**Question**: Where do I have to put the "FindLongLines" object so as to run the code and obtain the results higlighted in green?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the content of file named `LongLines.scala`:

```
import scala.io.Source

object LongLines {

  def processFile(filename: String, width: Int) {
    val source = Source.fromFile(filename)
    for(line <- source.getLines())
      processLine(filename, width, line)
  }

  private def processLine(filename: String, width: Int, line: String) {
    if (line.length > width)
      println(filename +": " + line.trim)
  }
}

object FindLongLines {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val width = args(0).toInt
    for (arg <- args.drop(1))
      LongLines.processFile(arg, width)
  }
}
```

You have several options how you could invoke it

**First option: Compile then run**

You first have to invoke the compiler:

```
scalac LongLines.scala
```

This will generate a bunch of `.class` files in the current directory. One such file will be called something like `FindLongLines.class`. Now you can invoke

```
scala FindLongLines 42 LongLines.scala
```

Here, `FindLongLines` is the name of the compiled class, `42` is `arg(0)` and `LongLines.scala` is `arg(1)` passed to the `main` of `FindLongLines`.
This roughly corresponds to `javac Foo.java` + `java Foo`

**Run as script**

Since all your code is in a single file, you could also run it as a script:

```
scala LongLines.scala 42 LongLines.scala
```

Here, `LongLines.scala` is the name of the script to run, and `42` and the second `LongLines.scala` are passed as `arg(0)` and `arg(1)` to the main method.

Both variants should produce the same result.